# can't print the struct data using scala

Tags: scala, rdd

i'd like to print scala struct data ,like that

```
res0.take(2).foreach{case (id,tags) => println(id,tags)}
```

But tags is struct data,so the output result is not expected.
And code is changed to `res0.take(2).foreach{case (id,tags) => println(id,tags.topic.id)}`,it will report that error: too many arguments for method println: (x: Any)Unit
how can i correct it?

Answer (score 1):

Use string interpolation to create a single `String` argument to `println()` out of many `String` elements.

```
println(s"$id, ${tags.topic.id}")
```

Comment: res1.take(2).foreach{case(userid,tags)=>println(s"$userid, ${tags.topicInterests.name}")} but it still report that name is not a member of Array.In fact,name is belonged to tags.topicInterests

Comment: @刘米兰 1 - That is a different question. 2 - The compiler is **always** correct.